# When should you use different numeric types in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

What are the pros and cons of different numeric types? In particular when should you use inexact floating values vs exact floating values?

And is there a difference between `decimal` and `numeric`? When should each be used?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The manual actually is pretty good at explaining it: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-numeric.html

`decimal` and `numeric` are the same.

Floating point by definition is inexact. It is faster and usually it's precision is good enough. For example if we use `real` type and store a distance in kilometres it would still be precise down to one milimetre.

However there are places when you need to use precise numbers, for example money transactions.